# How to make multiple publisher run concurrently in rti_connext?

Tags: data-distribution-service

I have created publisher and subscribers in RTI_CONNEXT which are able to communicate concurrently over a particular domain. I want publishers with multiple writers running concurrently. Do I need to use threads or RTI has provision of the same.

Also later I want to include publisher and writer into same participant. How to do that ?

Code will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: _Also later I want to include publisher and writer into same participant._ Did you mean _publisher_ and _subscriber_?

Comment: Yes publisher and subscriber. Sorry for that mistake.